Copying data from multiple sheets into one table
I have five tabs with tables in the same format. I want the data to be compiled into one, already existing sheet.
I want only the data, without the headers.
I would like the sheet with the compiled data to be cleared out each time I run the macro to avoid duplicates.
The data in each table starts in the third row. The range of the data will change dynamically with each input, but the amount of columns will remain the same.
I would like the data copied one under the other without gaps.
Sub ConsolidateData()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim destSheet As Worksheet
   Dim lastRow As Long
   Dim destRow As Long
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim sourceSheets As Variant
   Dim sheetName As Variant
   '
   sourceSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5") '
   ' Define the destination sheet
   Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects consolidated")
   ' Clear existing data from the destination sheet, starting from row 3
   destSheet.Rows("3:" & destSheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents
   ' 
   destRow = 3
   ' 
   For Each sheetName In sourceSheets
       Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
       ' 
       lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       ' 
       If lastRow > 2 Then
           ' Define the range to copy (all columns, from row 3 to last row)
           Set rng = ws.Range("A3:Z" & lastRow) ' 
           ' 
           rng.Copy Destination:=destSheet.Cells(destRow, 1)
           ' 
           destRow = destRow + rng.Rows.Count
       End If
   Next sheetName
End Sub


What is wrong with your code? Assuming that your workbook contains the sheets you are using in your code, it looks good to me.

I have no idea to be frank. I can't find the issue either. I only need 5 sheets to be copied to the compiled sheet, but when I tried copying everything to try if the code actually works, it doesn't read the data that I actually want to copy for some reason and only copies the remaining sheets. I'm out of answers and really losing my patience here.

@Longer in the VBA editor of Excel you can execute each line of code one after the other by pressing F8. This way you can easily find out what line of code does deviate from what you expect it to do!

Do all the sheets you want to copy have data in column A ? after lastRow = ... add debug.print ws.Name, lastRow and check results in the immediate window.

You are almost there. You can simplify the code by just looping over the Worksheets object instead of specifying all the names (except if you have some more sheets that you do not want to copy. In this case just use the names array to check if ws.Name is in the array).
Sub ConsolidateData()
    Dim ws as Worksheet, destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow as Long, destRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
   
    ' Define the destination sheet
    Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects consolidated")
    ' Clear existing data from the destination sheet, starting from row 3
    destSheet.Rows("3:" & destSheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents
   
    destRow = 3
    
    ' loop throug all worksheets
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ' only copy if its not the destination worksheet
        If ws.Name <> destSheet.Name Then
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            
            If lastRow > 2 Then
                ' Define the range to copy (all columns, from row 3 to last row)
                Set rng = ws.Range("A3:Z" & lastRow)
                
                rng.Copy Destination:=destSheet.Cells(destRow, 1)
                
                destRow = destRow + rng.Rows.Count
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub


Be careful with your variable declararions. You need to specify the type for every variable. If you use Dim ws, destSheet As Worksheet,  your variable ws is declared as Variant. You should use  Dim ws As Worksheet, destSheet As Worksheet
